# Is this valid code?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at some javascript code and I see the following:

```js
if(!+val)
     return val;
```

I've never seen `!+` before and find no reference to it when I search using Google.  If it is valid, what specifically is it used for?

Comment: Think of it as !(+val)...

Comment: Are you after an explanation of what it does? If that's the case, that needs to be your question.

Comment: There are validators, on the internet, that allow you to discover, for yourself, whether code 'is valid,' or not. Such as: [JS Hint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: @AdrianWragg He does ask that. `If it is valid, what specifically is it used for?` It's a fairly clear question, I don't see why so many people don't seem to like to.

Comment: To be fair, I added "If it is valid, what specifically is it used for?" after Adrian Wragg commented.  Apologies for the noob question, and thanks for the clarification/answer.

Comment: @Phrank No problem; it's actually turned into quite an interesting question now, it's just a shame that most downvoters won't necessarily return to revoke their votes.

Comment: @David Thomas, when I used JS Hint, it said "Confusing use of '!'."  

And also, your condescending tone came across clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) coerces a value to a `Number` and the [`!` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) performs logical negation.

That is, it is equivalent to

```
if(!Number(val))
```

For example,

```
!+"0"  // true, because +"0" === 0, and !0 === true
!+[1]  // false, because +[1] === 1 and !1 === false
```

Answer (score 2):

`!` is the [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT).

`+` is the [unary plus operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

`+val` converts `val` to a number. Then `!+val` negates it to boolean.

Comment: And if it can't be converted to a Number it returns `NaN`. +{valueOf: function() {return 'a'}} // NaN

Comment: @Moogs Ironically, `NaN` ("Not-a-Number") has, in fact, `Number` type. So technically it can always be converted to [`Number` type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.20), but not always to a [`Number` value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19).

Answer (score 0):

`+` converts a string to an int, and converts a date to an epoch timestamp. Everything else is self explanatory.

CORRECTION: converts it to a Number and not an int

Comment: It does not convert a string to an integer: console.log(+'1.2'); // 1.2 http://jsbin.com/dehakozoqe/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: coerce entails conversion, and int and number are conflated in javascript since they're is nothing called int on its own. Why so bugged down on details?

Comment: int implies decimals are truncated. Your answer can confuse people coming from statically typed languages.